# Export function of one component and use it in another one

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two below components: `Dialog` and `App`

`Dialog.js`

```
export var showDialog = function (_content, _title, _style = {maxWidth: "70%", top:"10%"}) {
    this.setState({
        open: true,
        title: _title,
        content: _content,
        style: _style
    });
};

export var hideDialog = function (_showConfirm , message) {
            this.setState({open: false});
    };

class DialogImport extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            open: false
        };
        showDialog = showDialog.bind(this);
        hideDialog = hideDialog.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        ....
        );
    }
}
```

and `App.js`

```
...
render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
                <React.Suspense fallback={loading()}>
                    <MessageBox/>
                    <Dialog/>
                    <DialogSecond/>
                    <ProgressCustom/>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/sso/login" component={Login}></Route>
                        ....
                        
                    </Switch>
                </React.Suspense>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
```

Assume I want to show the dialog inside `Login` component, all I need to do is import `showDialog` and `hideDialog` from `Dialog.js` and use it normally. My question is how to achieve this in functional components ? Can I just export simply the function like in class component or I have to normally pass through props or use `dispatch` method of `Redux` if my component tree is too complicated ?

Comment: Have you tried out your class-based solution? It won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how to achieve this in functional components ?

The fundamental answer there is: By [writing a hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html). There are a dozen different ways you could write this specific hook, but here's one example:

```
function useDialogState(dialog, startsOpen = false) {
    const [dialog, setDialog] = useState(initialState);
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(startsOpen);
    return [dialog, open, setOpen];
}
```

which you'd use like this:

```
function Example() {
    const [hiThereDialog, hiThereDialogOpen, hiThereDialogSetOpen] = useDialogState({
        title: "Hi there",
        content: "...",
        style: /*...*/,
    });

    return (
        // ...other stuff...
        // The dialog:
        {hiThereDialogOpen &&
            <Dialog {...hiThereDialog} />
        }
    );
}
```

or perhaps like this:

```
const hiThereDialogSettings = {
    title: "Hi there",
    content: "...",
    style: /*...*/,
};
function Example() {
    const [hiThereDialog, hiThereDialogOpen, hiThereDialogSetOpen] = useDialogState(hiThereDialogSettings);

    return (
        // ...other stuff...
        // The dialog:
        {hiThereDialogOpen &&
            <Dialog {...hiThereDialog} />
        }
    );
}
```

...assuming in both cases that you have a `Dialog` component that accepts `title`, `content`, and `style` props.

You'd open/close the dialog with:

```
setHiThereDialogOpen(true /* or false */);
```

or toggle it like this:

```
setHiThereDialogOpen(open => !open);
```

But again, **that's just an example**. There are a dozen other ways you could do this. (Or you could not do it at all, and just use `useState` directly for the open/closed flag and code the dialog content directly.)